How to create class by name "class"
I have input payload model (JSON) which contains JSON object by name class. I have to create a mapping class for JSON but since it contains the restricted keyword class, I cannot use it.
Below is the JSON to be mapped in the class:
"item": {
    "items": [
        {
            "department": {
                "id": "5",
                "refName": "test"
            },
            "class": {
                "id": "2",
                "refName": "test"
            }
        }
    ]
}

I have to use the above payload for the POST operation but since it contains the keyword class, I cannot use it. How can I achieve this?

Did you try using JsonPropertyAttribute https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm ? You can name that class what ever you want and set attribute to "class"

Since it's a property of the parent class, you should be able to use the [JsonProperty("class")] attribute to serialize/deserialize with a special name. You don't actually need to match the class name to the property.

This question is similar to: How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You also could use @class if you don't want to use JsonProperty attribute.
It can be read here:

Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They can't be used as identifiers in your program unless they include @ as a prefix. For example, @if is a valid identifier, but if isn't because if is a keyword.


class is a C# reserve keyword. Instead, you should work with JsonPropertyAttribute (from Newtonsoft.Json) or JsonPropertyName (from System.Text.Json).
For Newtonsoft.Json:
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[JsonProperty("class")]
public Class Class { get; set; }

For System.Text.Json:
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

[JsonPropertyName("class")]
public Class Class { get; set; }

